# Generating element's left offset with jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops, each

```
$("#footer div ul li").each(function(a) {
    $("#footer div ul li:nth-child(" + a + ")").css({
        left : 275*a - 275 + "px"
    });
});
```

I want to generate all li's left offset with jQuery. 
First element should have left:0px, second 275px, third 550px, etc.
I found there's something like .each() loop, but it works only for first element.
Could somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "but it works only for first element" --- and what's with next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `this`

```
 $("#footer div ul li").each(function(a) {
         $(this).css({
            left : 275*a - 275 + "px"
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$("#footer div ul li").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).css({
        left : 275*index + "px"
    });
});
```

?

index should be 0-based, so I don't know why you're then subtracting 275 (that should give -275px, 0px, 275px, ...)

You could also just manipulate the domElement that jQuery passes in, like this:

```
$("#footer div ul li").each(function(index, element) {
    element.style.left = 275*index + "px";
});
```